# How to use GET to retrieve check box selected value in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I am using Mysql PDO query to fetch the required result and it is saved in and array $newfamily. Now with the help of this array I am implementing check-box with the given code-

```
<form method="get" action="specific_family.php">
  <?php
    foreach($newfamily as $name)
            {
  ?>
        <input type='checkbox'<?php echo $name;?>"><?php echo $name;?></input>
 <?php
            } 
 ?>
 </select> <input type = "submit" name="submit" >
 </form>
```

Now in **specific_family.php** how can I retrieve al the selected check-box values in an array ? 
Also when I use back button of browser I can see previously selected values as ticked. How can I remove this ?

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the name attribute to your input thus:

```
 <form method="get" action="specific_family.php">
  <?php
    foreach($newfamily as $name)
            {
  ?>
                <label for="<?php echo $name?>"><?php echo $name?></label>
                <input type='checkbox' name="<?php echo $name;?>" id="<?php echo $name;?>"></input>
 <?php
            } 
 ?>
 </select> <input type = "submit" name="submit" >
 </form>
```

then your checkboxes will show up by name in your $_GET array.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I tried this, but this way i can't see the checkbox names :(

Comment: Sorry, I failed to throw in labels of any kind. See edit. casewarecomputers.com:8088/test.php

Answer (score 3):

The checkbox should have:

- A label

The checkbox needs:

- A name attribute
- A value attribute

It must not have:

- An end tag (unless you are using XHTML)

So:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox"
      name="new_families[]"
      value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>
</label>
```

The values of all the checked checkboxes will then appear in the array `$_GET['new_families']` when the form is submitted.